# Data table distorts after refreshing data

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a data table that represents data like this:
[image]

after clicking the edit marker (pencil icon) i can edit some fields. The fields need to be validated and if it fails the fields have to reset. I do this in the managed bean of the view using `p:ajax event="rowEditInit"` to save the attributes before saving and `ajax event="rowEdit"`to do the actual validation. if validation fails i return the previously saved values. if validation is correct i save the data to the database and load the collection again. Then i

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("vesselBalticSegmentCreateForm")
```

to reload the view.
Doesnt matter if the validation fails and i set the values back or it succeeds and i save/reload data the table breaks becoming like this:
[image]

seems to load only the edited row. and loads both edit/list modes.
any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The primeFaces RowEdit functionality already updates the row, also updating the table does by design not work (not sure if it is intentional, but that is just how it is). I know there is a duplicate of this Q/A on stackoverflow, I just do not seem to be able to find it. Someone might be able to create a patch/workaround, e.g. try on the prerenderview event to remove the id's of id's in the individual row that was edited. I don't have the time to try to create one.